# How can I get the version number to display in Layout from currently built Octpack nupkg?

Tags: octopus-deploy, octopack

Below are the steps taking place

- OctoPack: Attempting to build package from
  'MySoltuion.MyProject.nuspec'.
- OctoPack: Successfully created package
  'C:\pathToMySolution\MyProject\obj\octopacked\MyProject.**2018.03.26.6654**.nupkg'.
- OctoPack: OctoPack successful

I want to get the version i.e **2018.03.26.6654**.
FYI, I don't need my assembly version

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Taken the package was generated with [the version correctly](https://octopus.com/docs/packaging-applications/package-id), then this `Use the version number from an included package` should work.

Comment: Yes I was thinking that, do you have any idea how can i pick the version from octopacked folder and save it in config file

Comment: You only need to correctly generate the NuGet package version, whether going through octopack and replacement tokens, pre-build action to populate the version in .nuspec, or any other approach.

Answer (score 0):

OctoPack cannot resolve the tokens in the nuspec from the project file (unfortunately). 
Only from the build parameters (OctoPackNuGetProperties).

```
msbuild MySolution.sln /t:Build /p:RunOctoPack=true "/p:OctoPackNuGetProperties=suffix=release;title=My Title;version=1.0.0;myname=Paul"
```

See: [UsingOctoPack-Replacementtokens](https://octopus.com/docs/packaging-applications/creating-packages/nuget-packages/using-octopack#UsingOctoPack-Replacementtokens)

I am not sure myself if I will switch to a script with nuget to pack and push, so I can have the token replacements from the project file.

Btw.: It does work if you do not have a nuspec file, and Octopack generates one from the csproj file. But I would like to have my own nuspec, with a valid project url, dependencies, etc.